# Can't save field translation

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I have 2 languages on my site (English and Russian). I also have a content type "Home page"  and some fields are translantable (configured in admin/config/regional/content-language)

After saving the content in russian translation, changes are saving in english and russian. What i have to do to save these fields for just one language?

Drupal version: 9.3.5

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect setup of the Drupal site/fields. Drupal will not override the other translations if fields translations are configured correctly. I suppose you use paragraphs and probably enable the paragraph reference fields translation instead of fields translations inside the paragraph. Need more input from your side about the problem.